# Using Promises in AngularJS for chaining in two different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `provider` for my REST-Services named `MyRestServices`:

```
app.provider('MyRestServices', function() {
  this.baseUrl = null;
  this.setBaseUrl = function(_baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = _baseUrl;
  };

  this.$get = ['$http', function($http) {
    var _baseUrl = this.baseUrl;

    function getMyData() {
      return $http.get(_baseUrl + 'data1/?token=' + token + '&key=' + key);
    }

    function preGetTokenAndKey() {
      return $http.get(_baseUrl + 'keyAndToken/');
    }

    return {
      getMyData: getMyData,
      preGetTokenAndKey: preGetTokenAndKey
    };
  }];
});
```

I configure it before calling the first REST service.

```
app.config(function(MyRestServicesProvider) {
  MyRestServicesProvider.setBaseUrl('https://www.test.com/rest/');
});
```

And then I have a `HeadCtrl` controller which should call `preGetTokenAndKey` to get `key` and `token` which is needed for some other REST calls like `getMyData`.

```
app.controller('HeadCtrl', function (MyRestServices) {
  MyRestServices.preGetTokenAndKey().success(function(data) {
    var key = data.dataSection.key;
    var token = data.dataSection.token;
  });
});
```

My problem is I want to call `getMyData` from another controller, but I need `key` and `token` to make this call.
So I need to wait until `preGetTokenAndKey` was successful and I have to provide the two values to the `MyRestServices` provider.
How can I solve these problems?

Comment: may be resolve could be the way take a look at https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c or you could set up a 'fake' controller in a abstract ui-router block

Comment: One way would be to use eventing.. But what can you cache `preGetTokenAndKey` request ? so that both controllers can make the call independently? and remove the cache based on which ever condition  you want to clean it up..? Is it that both the controllers are run at the same time?

Comment: Also if you are using `preGetTokenAndKey` only to call `getMyData` then just do the call inside `getMyData` itself.

Comment: I have more than two controllers which need the data of ``preGetTokenAndKey``. It would be great if I can save the result so that I can use it in every other controller. And yes, they are running at the same time.

Comment: @Tim Sure then there is another option.  You can cache the promise so that the backend call is not made again. You can use eventing. but eventing for achieving synchronization issue is not good IMHO.

Comment: So what should I do? I thought I can save ``token`` and ``key`` inside ``MyRestServices`` so I can access it every time I will needed to. And I need some kind of mechanism, so that I know that the REST call ``preGetTokenAndKey`` was successfully finished.

Comment: @Tim Yes you can cache the promise,  Is there any point when your token will expire?

Comment: Yes, logout or change of profile, then I need to re-call the ``preGetTokenAndKey``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a better solution would be to chain them within your service itself. You'd setup your own promise within preGetTokenAndKey, which gets resolved by the $http call. Subsequent calls to preGetTokenAndKey() would just return the already resolved data w/o making additional $http calls.

So something along the lines of the following should get you started:

```
app.provider('MyRestServices', function() {
  this.baseUrl = null;
  this.setBaseUrl = function(_baseUrl) {
      this.baseUrl = _baseUrl;
  };

  this.$get = ['$http', function($http) {
    var _baseUrl = this.baseUrl;
    var _tokenAndKey = {};

    function getMyData() {
      return preGetTokenAndKey().then(function (data) {
            return $http.get(_baseUrl + 'data1/?token=' + data.dataSection.token + '&key=' + data.dataSection.key);
      });
    }

    function preGetTokenAndKey() {
      if(!_tokenAndKey.set) {
           _tokenAndKey.deferred = $http.get(_baseUrl + 'keyAndToken/').then(function(data) {
                _tokenAndKey.set = true;
                return data;
           });
      }
      return _tokenAndKey.deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
      getMyData: getMyData,
      preGetTokenAndKey: preGetTokenAndKey
    };
  }];
});
```

Comment: Right, if `preGetTokenAndKey` is _only_ being used to get the data i would have done this myself as well, but you dont have to create a defered object... Just return the promise...

Comment: @PSL - The reason to create the deferred object is to avoid constantly re-issuing the $http.get request for the keyAndToken since presumably we only need to do that once.

Comment: You are not doing that though, also you can achieve that using the http promise itself (Do not have to create on yourself).

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you just return $http.get(_baseUrl + 'keyAndToken/'); that it will issue that HTTP get request every time the method is called. Creating our own promise allows us to only do it once, even if preGetTokenAndKey() is called by many other controllers/service methods.

Comment: Now i see it - yes you are right. But my intention was to not issue that request everytime :) I'll update the code with a quick fix on that.

Comment: This is fine, except you can declare your deffered object for preGetTokenAndKey outside the function and cache the resopone

Comment: Just fixed that per discussion w/ PSL. Thanks

Comment: As soon as a controller shares, that's a service reference.

Comment: Is there a way to unset ``_tokenAndKey``? If the user change some values in the GUI, I have to re-fetch both values and so the other REST calls which will also be called can maybe access the old values.

Comment: Yeah this is better now.. I have removed my answer hence.. Actually again... You dont have to do `$q.defer()` instead just cache the http promise itself...

Comment: Okay, so with this solution, I have to write ``return preGetTokenAndKey().then(function (data)`` in every REST call which need the ``token`` (the token is for authentication like username / password)?

Comment: @Tim - yep. Keep in mind that promises have some extra benefits too (built in try/catch/finally handlers).

Comment: Okay, is there a nicer solution so that I can avoid this code duplication in every REST call?

Comment: You could send the token/key as part of the headers of every call, and do that automatically by configuring the $http service in your module's run() method. See "Setting HTTP Headers" @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @Tim Another way would to be to use httpInterceptor, intercept request and for your requests make the token call from the interceptor and set it as data and return your config from the interceptor.. This will make it put in a common place..

Comment: @PSL: Sounds great your idea, now I only have to realize it :-)

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is I want to call getMyData from another controller,

If so, you can use `$broadcast` to notify other controller that async call resolved and you have key/token

```
app.controller('HeadCtrl', function($rootScope, MyRestServices) {
    MyRestServices.preGetTokenAndKey().success(function(data) {
        var key = data.dataSection.key;
        var token = data.dataSection.token;

        $rootScope.$broadcast("getMyDataTrigger", {key: key,token: token}); 
    });
});
```

In other controller implement listener:

```
$rootScope.$on("getMyDataTrigger", function(event, data){

        if(data){
           MyRestServices.getMyData(data.key, data.token);
           // ...
        }

    });
```

---

Just override `getMyData`:

```
function getMyData(key, token) {
  return $http.get(_baseUrl + 'data1/?token=' + token + '&key=' + key);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already did this and of course it works. But I have the problem, that I have to do the REST call ``getMyData`` and some other in other controllers like I wrote in the headline of this issue.

Comment: Now the issue is that your controllers are tightly coupled and they need to be aware of the synchronization issue. :(

Comment: @PSL Well, Its design problem (I mean MVC) when one controller tells to other one to do async call. We can run the  chain on Service side and notify *all* controllers about resolving. Service can use only `$rootScope`